# Object of ViewController is set to Null

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

here I am creating an object of a viewController in storyboard to navigation

```
 FinalViewController *objct_finalView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"final"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objct_finalView animated:YES];
```

but while debugging it is not getting any memory

```
objct_finalView FinalViewController *   0x00000000
```

can any body please tell the reason , why it is happening?

Comment: make sure self.storyboard is not nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this two things:

1.- To get the storyboard do this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"yourStoryBoardName" bundle:nil];
```

2.-
Also check your FinalViewController in your storyboard you have to be sure the identifier is in the "identity inspector"-->"identity"-->StoryBoard ID:final

I hope this helps.